# Best practice for accessing parent query object from child components

Tags: apollo-client, vue-apollo

I have a "event" page that runs an Apollo query for an event with a given ID.  There are multiple child components that use the event object to access various properties.  I am struggling to find the best pattern for making that object available to the child components.  Do I want to have additional queries in the child components that just access the cache exclusively?  Or is there a way to have the components defer until the query is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I only run queries from "page" components and pass data down as props to lower level components:

So I would do something like

**/pages/EventPage.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <EventDetails :event="event">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventDetails from '/wherever/my/component/is/EventDetails.vue'
import MY_EVENT_QUERY from '/wherever/my/query/is/EventQuery.gql'

export default {
  apollo: {
    event: {
      query: MY_EVENT_QUERY
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**/components/EventDetails.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{event.name}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    event: {
      type: Object,
      default: { name: '' }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

There might be rare times where I would have a sub-component fetch its own data. I'm thinking of a form where you have select box that needs to load the list of dropdown items or something. But I would **not** re-query the same event item over and over again.